# Retrieve latest post by multiple categories with ID

Tags: posts, categories, wp-query, get-posts

I have the categories listed below in my `product` post type.

```
Category Name: Test 1 ID: 82
Category Name: Test 2 ID: 83
Category Name: Test 3 ID: 84
Category Name: Test 4 ID: 85
```

Now I want to retrieve for each category one post -- the last one added.

I have tried below code but it isn't working right.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'product_cat_' => 82,83,84,85, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ); 
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );    
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); 
?>  
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: your `$args` array is not valid php. [enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you pass multiple category to a query, then you'll retrieve 4 posts ordered by date, but if you last 4 posts are all in one category, you'll get all 4 posts from same category.

You have 2 choices: run 4 different queries, one per category, and retrieve one post per query or run a custom sql query that retrieve the posts taking care of getting one post per category.

I'll give you a solution for the second choice.

The code is most taken form [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120142/query-posts-but-only-return-1-from-a-custom-taxonomy).

```
function get_unique_post_by_tax( $tax = 'product_cat_', $ids = '', $cpt = 'product') {
  global $wpdb;
  $ids = array_filter( array_map( 'intval', (array) $ids ) );
  if ( empty($ids) ) return false;
  $ids_txt = implode( ',', $ids );
  return $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->term_relationships
    JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt 
    ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN $wpdb->posts AS p ON p.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = %s 
    AND tt.term_id = IN (%s)
    AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT %d",
    $tax, $cpt, $ids_txt, count($ids)
  ) );
}
```

Put previous function in `functions.php` after that, you can use it like so:

```
$loop = get_unique_post_by_tax( 'product_cat_', array(82,83,84,85) );

if ( ! empty($loop) ) {
  global $post;
  foreach ( $loop as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>;
  <?php
  endforeach;
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```